# Rails: Build object from "selected" object of a many-to-many relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, many-to-many

I'm working on a Rails app (my Rails skills is rusty). In it I currently have four models, User, Account, Collaborator (join table from User*-*Account) and Project. Each user can have many accounts which in it's turn can have many projects. I currently have some trouble with creating projects for the right account. My goal is to display the users accounts (could also be called i.e. Companies) and the accounts projects on the same page, and also have the projects create action on the same page. Something like this:

```
Logo 

(current_user) Account 1 (ie. Company account)
  Account Project 1
  Account Project 2
  text_field for creating new projects for Account 1 + submit button

(current_user) Account 2 (ie. My fun hobby projects)
  Account Project 1
  Account Project 2
  text_field for creating new projects for Account 2 + submit button
```

I don't have any problems with creating users and account but I am unsure of how to achieve the above result for creating Account projects.

The models and relationship for Account and Project looks like this:

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
  [...]
  has_many :projects, dependent: :destroy
  [...]

class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  [...]
  belongs_to :account
end
```

I have made a stumbling attempt to create new projects like this:

```
class ProjectsController < ApplicationController
  [...]  
  def create
    # How do I find the selected/correct account?
    @project = "selected_account".projects.build(params[:projects])
    if @project.save
      flash[:success] = "Project created!"
      redirect_to root_path
    else
      render 'pages/home'
    end
  end
```

My question can probably be narrowed off to how do I find the selected/correct account in ProjectControllers create action?

Any answers, guidance or tips would be great.

Thanks.

Comment: Retagged to remove ruby, since this is rails specific

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming you have a "current user" method that returns the current logged in user, you could try something like:

Add to routes

```
resources :accounts do
  resources :projects
end
```

Check routes

..from command line do 'rake routes'

```
account_projects GET    /accounts/:account_id/projects(.:format)     projects#index
                 POST   /accounts/:account_id/projects(.:format)     projects#create
```

POST /accounts/1/projects

```
class ProjectsController < ApplicationController
  [...]  
  def create
    account = current_user.accounts.find params[:account_id]
    @project = account.projects.build(params[:projects])
    if @project.save
      flash[:success] = "Project created!"
      redirect_to root_path
    else
      render 'pages/home'
    end
  end 
end
```

Comment: Thanks, I have one related question. I tried your approach but I moved it to my "home" action in another controller like this: `account = current_user.accounts.where(:id => 1)
    @project = account.projects.build if signed_in?` (:id => 1 is for testing). But now I get `undefined method `projects' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation:0x007fa063c70f00>` despite that I have set up the relationships as above. Do you know why that is? Thanks.

Comment: Check the api and see if you can recreate in rails console

Comment: Thanks for your answer and comments. I decided to use a hidden field where I pass along the account_id, with an almost identical solution as you pointed out: `account = current_user.accounts.find(params[:project][:account_id])
    @project = account.projects.build(params[:project])`. However, don't know if my solution is correct according to "The Rails Way", nor super-secure. Might ask another question for that purpose. But thanks!